# Why am I getting `0/1 nodes are available` when running Docker Desktop?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-statefulset

I'm running Docker Desktop with Kubernetes.

I can ssh to the node and I have other pods running on the node.

However, when I apply a StatefulSet to the cluster I get:

```
0/1 nodes are available: 1 pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims. preemption: 0/1 nodes are available: 1 Preemption is not helpful for scheduling.
```

The Stateful Set is here:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/#components

```
kubectl get no
NAME             STATUS   ROLES           AGE    VERSION
docker-desktop   Ready    control-plane   6d2h   v1.24.1
```

Comment: please show the output of kubectl get no

Comment: Edited - see above.

Comment: Do you have an eligible persistent volume defined? The message is telling you the issue: *1 pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims*

Comment: I've no idea. I'm just applying the YAML here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/#components
There's no mention of a PVC there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are applying the manifest defined [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/#components) as it is, the problem is in the below snippet, particularly with the `storageClassName.`  Likely, your cluster does **not** have a storage class called `my-storage-class.`

```
 volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: www
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      storageClassName: "my-storage-class"
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 1Gi
```

To get the definitive error statement, you can run the following command:

```
kubectl describe  pvc www-web-0
```

you will notice something like:

```
storageclass.storage.k8s.io "my-storage-class" not found
```

**Solution:**

You can run the following command to get your cluster's available `storage class` and replace it in yaml file.

```
kubectl get sc
```

Alternatively, you can delete the `storageClassName` and let the default storage class do the magic. However, for this to work, you must have a default sc present in your cluster.

If you have no storage class present, you need to create one. Check [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/) out.

Comment: In my case, it is `storageClassName: gp2`. But still showing same error in pod event.
`0/4 nodes are available: 4 node(s) didn't match Pod's node affinity/selector. preemption: 0/4 nodes are available: 4 Preemption is not helpful for scheduling.`

Answer (score 0):

if your using k8s locally with docker desktop ensure that the storageClassName is set to "**hostpath**" below is one of my volumeClaimTemplates for a local redis cluster. The comment has saved me a few times when getting the "**0/1 nodes are available**" which is a confusing error

```
  volumeClaimTemplates:
- metadata:
    name: data
  spec:
    accessModes: ["ReadWriteOnce"]
    ##############################
    ## this will catch you out ##
    # for Docker Desktop (Local K8s Cluster) set to -> storageClassName: "hostpath"
    ##############################
    storageClassName: "hostpath"
    resources:
      requests:
        storage: 250Mi
```

Answer (score -1):

I was also facing the same issue with Mac Apple M1 Pro. I also found related issue on github.
https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/2560

I was getting exact same error described in above github issue by following mentioned steps.

So as per suggestions in that thread, I have tried `Reset Kubernetes cluster`, `Clean/Purge Data` and `Reset to Factory defaults` from Troubleshoot section. But none of them worked for me.

Finally,  I have entirely uninstalled Docker desktop and reinstalled it again by downloading latest installer from official site, which has fixed the issue. Now, I am getting `Bound` status instead of `Pending` when I can pvc.